# What is responsible for this TypeError: DataUndersampler.transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

This is a custom support vectorbased data undersampler answer from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76396909/10309712).

The main idea is to undersample the majority class in an informed way, by fitting an SVC to the data, find the support vectors, and then undersample the majority class based on the distances to these support vectors.

Code:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.utils import resample
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

class DataUndersampler(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, random_state=None):
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.svc = SVC(kernel='linear')

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Fit SVC to data
        self.svc.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y):
        # Get support vectors
        support_vectors = self.svc.support_vectors_
        # Get indices of support vectors
        support_vector_indices = self.svc.support_

        # Separate majority and minority classes
        majority_class = y.value_counts().idxmax()
        minority_class = y.value_counts().idxmin()
        X_majority = X[y == majority_class]
        y_majority = y[y == majority_class]
        X_minority = X[y == minority_class]
        y_minority = y[y == minority_class]

        # Calculate distances of majority class samples to nearest support vector
        distances = np.min(np.linalg.norm(X_majority.values[:, np.newaxis] - support_vectors, axis=2), axis=1)

        # Sort the majority class samples by distance and take only as many as there are in minority class
        sorted_indices = np.argsort(distances)
        indices_to_keep = sorted_indices[:len(y_minority)]

        # Combine the undersampled majority class with the minority class
        X_resampled = pd.concat([X_majority.iloc[indices_to_keep], X_minority])
        y_resampled = pd.concat([y_majority.iloc[indices_to_keep], y_minority])

        return X_resampled, y_resampled
```

MWE:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10_000, n_classes=5, weights=[22.6, 3.7, 16.4, 51.9],
                           n_informative=4)

rf_clf = model = RandomForestClassifier()
resampler = DataUndersampler(random_state=234)

pipeline = Pipeline([('sampler', resampler), ('clf', rf_clf)])
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(estimator=pipeline)

classifier.fit(X, y)
```

Produces the error:

```py
----> 7 classifier.fit(X, y)

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py in wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138     @wraps(f)
    139     def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140         data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141         if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142             # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition

TypeError: DataUndersampler.transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `TransformerMixin` as its implementation of `fit_transform` is:

```py
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    """
    Fits transformer to `X` and `y` with optional parameters `fit_params`
        and returns a transformed version of `X`.
    """
        if y is None:
            # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
        else:
            # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X) # <-- here is the problem
```

Solution implement `fit_transform` yourself.
(That is the main purpose of the `TransformerMixin` class - beside also also inheriting from `_SetOutputMixin` [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/base.py#L875)).

```
class DataUndersampler(BaseEstimator):

    def fit_transform(self, X, y):
        return self.fit(X, y).transform(X, y)

    ...
```

---

NOTE:
You might run into problems further down the line if only a single output from transform is expected.
In that case you have to update Y inplace and only return X.

```
y[:] = y_resampled
return X_resampled
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Let's slowly take this step by step. First let's look at the error.

> TypeError: DataUndersampler.transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

This error happens when a function expects 2 arguments but gets only one. For example:

```
def func (x , y):
    return x, y # Fummy function

# This causes the error:
func(3) # Not enough arguments
```

Thus, whatever is calling `transform()` is only expecting transform to accept 1 argument.

Indeed, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/multiclass.py#L669) for [`OneVsOneClassifier.fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.fit), we see this line:

```
     # Note transform is called with only 1 argument!
     Y = self.label_binarizer_.fit_transform(y)
```

---

I'm not super familiar with Sklearn, but I suspect that you need a classifier that can handle 2 input variables. I looked but couldn't figure out what that would be, though.